How to add ObjectBox dependencies to KMP project?
I have Kotlin Multiplatform project with next modules: composeApp(commonMain, desctopMain), server(main), shared(commonMain, jvmMain, commonTest, jvmTest).
How to add ObjectBox to jvmMain or commonMain? Following the objectbox's "getting started" guide and google doesn't help.
First i have: "Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name"
root gradle:
plugins {
    // this is necessary to avoid the plugins to be loaded multiple times
    // in each subproject's classloader
    alias(libs.plugins.composeMultiplatform) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinJvm) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform) apply false
}

buildscript{
    val objectboxVersion by extra("4.0.3")
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("io.objectbox:objectbox-gradle-plugin:$objectboxVersion")
    }
}

shared module gradle:

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") 
    id("io.objectbox") 
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            // put your Multiplatform dependencies here
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

When I am trying to resolve this problem by commenting
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")

i get this one : "An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'io.objectbox']

Failed to apply plugin 'io.objectbox'.
'io.objectbox' can only be applied to a project if one of the following is applied before:
* an Android plugin
* the Kotlin Android or JVM plugin
* the Java Library, Java Application or Java plugin"

and shared build gradle looks so:

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
//    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm")
    id("io.objectbox")
}

kotlin {
    jvm()
    
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            // put your Multiplatform dependencies here
        }
        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }
}

So, this is closed circle for me. I tried a lot(a much more described here, this only what in "getting started guide" described), but nothing help.

https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-java/issues/601 should answer your question. Short answer: It's not really possible, but can be with boilerplate and some caveats.

@Uwe - ObjectBox how it can be with boilerplate and some caveats? I can add objectbox to jvmMain with boilerplate, but MyObjectBox class is not generated. May be you can explain how exactly to do it with "with boilerplate and some caveats"?

Kindly look at the GitHub issue I linked. For example, the first comment contains a link to another Stack Overflow post with more details.
